# autoconf looking for a folder that doesn't exist

Tags: perl, autoconf

I've been setting up a PHP development environment on my Sierra Mac. I now have it mostly working, but need to install the `intl` extension on PHP.

I've tried

```
sudo pecl install intl
```

but it's throwing the following error:

```
/usr/local/autoconf/bin/autoconf: /usr/local/mac-dev-env/autoconf-2.69/bin/autom4te: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/autoconf/bin/autoconf: line 505: /usr/local/mac-dev-env/autoconf-2.69/bin/autom4te: Undefined error: 0
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

It looks like it's looking for the Perl executable in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/perl`, which no longer exists, as I've since uninstalled `XAMPP`. Perl is now located at `/usr/bin/perl`.

How do I change the location in `autoconf`?

Comment: I think you are using a program (`/usr/local/mac-dev-env/autoconf-2.69/bin/autom4te`) that was installed using the `perl` you uninstalled. You could try editing its shebang line to use a different `perl`, but this "new" `perl` might not have every dependency of the script installed. The better solution is to reinstall that program with the "new" `perl`.

Comment: Yes... what do you mean by 'shebang line'?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The file warned that it was autogenerated, but I changed the path in it anyway, and that seemed to be fine. Also had to change the corresponding line in another file called 'autoheader' - just leaving this here in case it helps someone else!

Comment: You might want to write that up as an answer and accept it. That would be useful for future readers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Ikegami, here's what worked:

Opened autom4te (at /usr/local/mac-dev-env/autoconf-2.69/bin/autom4te, as specified in the error message).

The comment at the top said that this file should not be edited as it's auto-generated, but I edited the line that referred to XAMPP, and changed the path to /usr/bin/perl

Ran "sudo pecl install intl" again, and ran into the same error with a few different programs (all within the autoconf-2.69 directory). Changed each of them to remove the reference to XAMPP, and replaced with the correct path.

Ran install command again, and it worked.